# Python: From where does plaform.architecture get 32/64 bit information?

Tags: python, windows, bit, platform, or-tools

I need everything (PyCharm, Python) to be in 64 bit for a project. I have been careful to install 64 bit versions of Python 3.7 and PyCharm. My laptop supports the 64 bit Windows OS. However, when I query `python -c "import platform; print(platform.architecture())`, it returns `('32bit', 'WindowsPE')`. Where is this 32 bit coming from? According to this discussion on GitHub (https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/509), it is critical to be in 64-bit to install ortools from Google.

[image: Screenshot of my PyCharm terminal]

Thanks for your help! I am relatively inexperienced with this, if this post needs more clarity let me know and I'll do my best!

Comment: In pycharm go to `settings -> project -> Python interpreter` and create a new one with the correct 64 bit base interpreter. (Open a new terminal to test it)

Comment: Or-tools is 64 bit only

Comment: @Stradivari Thank you for the suggestion! It helped. If you have the time, could you explain why this helped? What was wrong with my old environment?

Comment: @AndreyRisukhin cheers, probably the base interpreter of the previous environment was a 32 bit one